# Kafka Connect - Deployment on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, google-cloud-dataproc

Planning to setup Kafka on GCP and read the Kafka topic from Dataproc.

Questions:

1. if we go with managed Kafka from GCP (https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/click-to-deploy-images/kafka), do we need to setup any Kafka connect APIs for Dataproc to be able to access the data from Kafka?
2. continuation of above, if we go with self hosted Kafka on GCP compute engine, where we launch a cloud compute engine, install zookeeper/kafka, do we need to deploy Kafka connect APIs for Dataproc to be able to access the data from Kafka?

Could you share any reference, if we need to deploy Kafka connect for one of the above approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Connect would be used to get data to or out of Dataproc, such as using GCS or HDFS Sink connectors, it's not a requirement for it

Alternatively, you could run Spark or Flink within Dataproc and skip Kafka Connect entirely, or try GCP Dataflow (Apache Beam) for the same